# how can i add a class to a specific img using jquery or php?

Tags: wordpress

im learning wordpress on a domain called lingeriesshop.net and i am working on installing a livechat console from the chat service provider mylivechat.com using there awesome wordpress plugin they have an option to assign a custom float image and another option to align it to the left or right side of the page in there chat settings, however when i align the image on the right side of the page i get 50px of space between the img and the edge of my page.

in the dashboard for there plugins chat settings they allow you to assign an image offset horizontally or vertically if i assign the image a horizontal offset of 50px it aligns perfectly to the page but when i open the chat window i lose 50px of the chat window itself and cannot close it. i cannot find any class names or id names using firebug to write a css adjustment and there script is generated serverside so i cant manually edit there files to adjust it either i did find this img tag controlling its position with firebug

```
<img style="white-space: nowrap; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;" src="http://lingeriesshop.net/redchatimage.png">
```

if i set in firebug a left position of 50px everything works great =) how can i add this style to this image without effecting other images on the page when i cant call it with a class or id of its own? is there a special way to add a class or id or inline style? i was wondering if i could do it with maybe some kind of "if" statement  like maybe, if is img "redchatimage.png" then something like position it left 50px.

im very new to WordPress and php and ive only done minor mod's to html with jquery, im great with css and html but its to no avail in this situation so is this impossible? this feature would really help  my design go farther and id love to see it implemented. =)

Comment: You are explaining a lot and showing no code. How is your HTML and CSS and how you want them to be? Did you research something about the needed jQuery commands?

Comment: In jQuery, `$("#imageID").addClass("classname");`

Comment: hi sorry about the no code i forgot to indent it so it wasnt appearing =) the jquery solution looks great tyme  how could i find the image id?

Comment: the problem im having brasofilo is that there chat service generates the code so i cant add or remove classes in a traditional way by editing core files and i found a command to add a class to every image on a page but thats not specific enough and i dont know about the image id or where its referenced becuase im new to wordpress the above img code is all i can see in firebug that is controlling it because if i add 50px to the left it works great how can i find the image id if there is one to use tymes solution and write a class to the image?.

Comment: there is also a div that if 50px is added to its left position it gets resolved in firebug                                                                  <div style="overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 50px; width: 80px; height: 195px;">

Comment: is there a way to add a class to a specific div that does not have an id or class to reference it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in jQuery, you can do this:

```
//Note I'm using jQuery instead of $....just to help out when using wordpress.
jQuery("img[src='http://lingeriesshop.net/redchatimage.png']").addClass('classname');
```

Comment: hi adam great answer thanks =) i opted to move the live chat to the other side of my site to add another sidebar because i couldnt get the image to move i tryed adding a class to the image using the above solution and also implementing special css to overpower the inline styles the chat plugin generated server side this answer would normally work perfectly and is exactly what i asked but it couldnt be done do to special circumstances =) i think the chats generated code was maybe protected somehow and couldnt be modified and the plugins core files didnt include styling for page output.

Comment: the chat image position is great on the left side of the page so its good enough for me right side implementation is at a loss lol =)